# 1364 - Field 'aim' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    1364 - Field 'aim' doesn't have a default value
Query:
    INSERT INTO mybb_users (`username`,`password`,`salt`,`loginkey`,`email`,`postnum`,`threadnum`,`avatar`,`avatartype`,`usergroup`,`additionalgroups`,`displaygroup`,`usertitle`,`regdate`,`lastactive`,`lastvisit`,`website`,`icq`,`yahoo`,`skype`,`google`,`birthday`,`signature`,`allownotices`,`hideemail`,`subscriptionmethod`,`receivepms`,`receivefrombuddy`,`pmnotice`,`pmnotify`,`showimages`,`showvideos`,`showsigs`,`showavatars`,`showquickreply`,`showredirect`,`tpp`,`ppp`,`invisible`,`style`,`timezone`,`dstcorrection`,`threadmode`,`daysprune`,`dateformat`,`timeformat`,`regip`,`language`,`showcodebuttons`,`sourceeditor`,`buddyrequestspm`,`buddyrequestsauto`,`away`,`awaydate`,`returndate`,`awayreason`,`notepad`,`referrer`,`referrals`,`buddylist`,`ignorelist`,`pmfolders`,`warningpoints`,`moderateposts`,`moderationtime`,`suspendposting`,`suspensiontime`,`coppauser`,`classicpostbit`,`usernotes`) VALUES ('rio','6db04d3a4e1c1f25eef276376e6fe59a','fOEYofMQ','0plMO4vfUU7WeKjUvMGJarO942RyR4zBPLm99WiH0HW6eNtdTj','rio11@protonmail.com',0,0,'','',2,'',0,'',1572470900,1572470900,1572470900,'',0,'','','','','',1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,'0',2,'linear',0,'','',X'ac45371d','',1,0,1,0,0,0,0,'','',0,0,'','','',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'')
```

i am getting this error can someone plz help

regards
rio

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE mybb_users`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty self-explanatory: You have a field named 'aim' but you are not assigning any value to it in your query. Database engine tries to assign its default value, but no default specified (and it's probably not nullable either)